# Merging pandas dataframe rows to create ranges?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

first post on SO and I'm fairly new to Python, so apologies if this question is trivial/has already been answered (I wasn't able to find it if it was).

I have a pandas dataframe `df` composed of genomic coordinates in the following format:

```
    chrom     start       end
0   chr22  10510357  10510357
1   chr22  10512304  10512304
2   chr22  10516109  10516109
3   chr22  10516111  10516111
4   chr22  10516129  10516129
5   chr22  10516130  10516130
6   chr22  10516131  10516131
7   chr22  10516133  10516133
8   chr22  10516161  10516161
9   chr22  10516162  10516162
10  chr22  10516163  10516163
11  chr22  10516164  10516164
12  chr22  10516165  10516165
13  chr22  10516166  10516166
14  chr22  10516167  10516167
15  chr22  10516168  10516168
16  chr22  10516169  10516169
17  chr22  10516170  10516170
18  chr22  10516171  10516171
19  chr22  10516172  10516172
```

What I'd like to do is merge rows where the 'end' position of the previous row is 1 base pair away from the 'start' position of the current row, hopefully ending up with something like this:

```
 chrom     start       end
0   chr22  10510357  10510357
1   chr22  10512304  10512304
2   chr22  10516109  10516109
3   chr22  10516111  10516111
4   chr22  10516129  10516129
5   chr22  10516130  10516133
6   chr22  10516161  10516172
```

I've been working on a small test data set that is just composed of positions in chr22, but for my actual script I'll be using the whole genome so checking if the chromosomes of adjacent positions are also the same is also important. Here's what I've tried so far with no luck:

```
for i in range(0, len(df)-1):
    if df.loc[i, 'chrom'] == df.loc[i+1, 'chrom'] and df.loc[i, 'end'] == df.loc[i+1, 'start']:
        df.loc[i, 'end'] = df.loc[i+1, 'end']
```

Thank you all in advance, any help/guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1],[3],[4],[5],[7], [11],[12],[13],[14],[18]])
df_end = df[~((df[0].shift(0) == df[0].shift(-1)-1))]
df_start = df[~((df[0].shift(0) == df[0].shift(+1)+1))]
for start, end in zip(df_start[0], df_end[0]):
    print (start, end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that "1 base pair away" means that the start position of the current row is equal to the value of the end position of the previous row plus 1.

```
import pandas as pd

#Function to find the end position of consecutive rows 
    def findEnd(df, index):
        while index < len(df)-1:
            if(df.iloc[index]['end']+1) == df.iloc[index+1]['start']:
                index+=1
            else: return(df.iloc[index]['end'], index)
        return (df.iloc[index]['end'], index)


    lst = []
    i = 0
    genLen = len(df)
    #Traverse entire dataframe
    while i < genLen:  
        #Check if we have at least one more row
        if i < genLen-1: 
            #Check the next row is the same chrom
            if(df.iloc[i]['chrom'] == df.iloc[i+1]['chrom']):
                start = df.iloc[i]['start']
                end,i = findEnd(df,i)
                lst.append([df.iloc[i]['chrom'],start,end])
            else:
                #if the next row is a different 
                lst.append(list(df.iloc[i]))
        elif i == genLen -1:
            lst.append(list(df.iloc[i]))
        i+=1

    chrom = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['chrom','start','end'])
```